# Need to find when Account field on opportunity enabled for tracking,

Tags: fields

In Opportunity field tracking, we have account field tracking enabled. This field was enabled for tracking few days ago. I want an exact date when this field was enabled. how can i find it.. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You can find this in the Setup Audit Trail. Go the `Setup | Security Controls | View Setup Audit Trail`. You will see the last 20 changes but can download a .csv file of the last 6 months worth of changes.

See the [Salesforce documentation](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorsetup.htm) for more detail.